# Code works line-by-line in command prompt, but new problem appears when I run the file as a whole

Tags: python, html, indexing, error-handling, beautifulsoup

I've just copied out the code used in a Python web scraping guide, and everything works fine when I test each line in the command prompt.

When I run the whole file, however, I get the message:

```
File "web_scrape_practice.py", line 23, in "module"
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?d=graphics+cards"

uReq(my_url)
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "item-container"})
container = containers[4]
brandDiv = container.find("div","item-info")

for container in containers:
    brand = brandDiv.div.img["title"]

    title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].text

    shipping_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()


    print("brand: " + brand)
    print("product_name: " + product_name)
    print("shipping: " + shipping)<br><br>
```

*line 23* is this one:

```
shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: *"everything works fine when I test each line in the command prompt."* are you testing this for every element of `containers`?

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range` means you are trying to access an object not in the list (for example accessing the 6th object of an 3 object long list).

That mean `container.findAll` somehow return an empty list. may test if the list at least 1 element long `if len(shipping_container) > 0`

Comment: the error is clear. the index is out of the range. use `try/except` or `if` condition to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are capturing items inside tag with `id=recommendItems` and they don't have any shipping info. The easiest solution is to exclude them from the search.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?d=graphics+cards"
page_soup = soup(requests.get(my_url).text, "html.parser")

for container in page_soup.select(':not(#recommendItems).items-view .item-container'):
    brand = container.select_one('a.item-brand img[alt]')['alt']
    product_name = container.select_one('a.item-title').get_text(strip=True)
    shipping = container.select_one('li.price-ship').get_text(strip=True)

    print("brand: ", brand)
    print("product_name: ", product_name)
    print("shipping: ", shipping)
```

Prints:

```
brand:  MSI
product_name:  MSI GeForce RTX 2070 DirectX 12 RTX 2070 GAMING 8G 8GB 256-Bit GDDR6 PCI Express 3.0 x16 HDCP Ready Video Card
shipping:  Free Shipping
brand:  EVGA
product_name:  EVGA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti DirectX 12 11G-P4-2281-KR 11GB 352-Bit GDDR6 PCI Express 3.0 HDCP Ready SLI Support BLACK EDITION GAMING Video Card, Dual HDB Fans & RGB LED
shipping:  $6.99 Shipping
brand:  MSI
product_name:  MSI GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER DirectX 12 RTX 2070 Super GAMING X 8GB 256-Bit GDDR6 PCI Express 3.0 x16 HDCP Ready SLI Support Video Card
shipping:  Free Shipping
brand:  ZOTAC

... and so on.
```